# Line chart axis zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've got some problems with my d3 visualization. I'm trying to do a line chart that shows a development over 15 years.

First problem is that the x-axis does't scale depending on the zoom.
I've used this to get started:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4dc8736fb1ce9799c6d6
But I don't know why my axis doesn't zoom.

Second, the axis labeling is wrong, it should be the week and the year (e.g.01-2016)

And the last: What opportunities do I have, if there is some data missing, for example the data for the year 2013? Can I have a break in the chart, so that there is just a white space for this year?

Here is the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test Tool</title> 
  </head> 

  <body>  
    <!--MAIN-->
    <main>

    <!--LINE CHART -->
    <script>
    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 570 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale().domain([-width / 2, width / 2])
        .range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([-height / 2, height / 2])
        .range([height, 0]);


    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function(d) { return d; })
        .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("dragend", dragended);

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.meldewoche); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.faelle); })
        .interpolate("basis");

    var areaflip = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.meldewoche); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(-d.faelle); })
        .interpolate("basis");

    // Define the line
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.meldewoche); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.faelle); })
        .interpolate("basis");

    var valuelineflip = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.meldewoche); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(-d.faelle); })
        .interpolate("basis");

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", 
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .call(zoom); 

    var container = svg.append("g");

    var rect = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all");

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("data-hanta-gesamt.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            // Parse the date / time
            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%W-%Y").parse;
            d.meldewoche = parseDate(d.meldewoche);
            d.faelle = +d.faelle; 
        });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.meldewoche; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.faelle+550; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    container.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(data))
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,-265)");
    container.append("path")
            .attr("class", "lineflip")
            .attr("d", valuelineflip(data))
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,-265)");

    container.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("d", area)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,-265)"); 
    container.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "areaflip")
            .attr("d", areaflip)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,-265)");

    });


    //ZOOM
    function zoomed() {
        container.select(".x axis").call(xAxis);
        container.select(".y axis").call(yAxis); 
        //svg.selectAll('.line').attr('d', line)  
      container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + ",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ",1)");

    }

    function dragstarted(d) {
      d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
      d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
    }

    function dragged(d) {
      d3.select(this)
          .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
          .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
    }

    function dragended(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
    }


    </script>
    </main>     
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
     body {
        background: #E1E2DD;
        color: #333;
        font: 1em/1em "Helvetica Neue";
      }

      #main {
        float: left;
        padding: 3em;
        width: 65%;
      }
      #footer {
        padding: 1em;
        text-align: right;
        width:65%; 
      }

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}       

.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}

.line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

.lineflip {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.area {
    fill: lightsteelblue;
      stroke-width: 0;
      fill-opacity: .67;
}

.areaflip {
    fill: lightsteelblue;
      stroke-width: 0;
      fill-opacity: .67;
}
```

The csv looks like this:

```
meldewoche,faelle
01-2001,2
03-2001,1
04-2001,2
05-2001,2
07-2001,1
08-2001,6
09-2001,1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to small changes to fix the issues you mentioned.

1. **Issue 1: the x-axis doesn't scale in response to the zoom.** The problem you're having comes from how you are updating the x- and y-axes in `zoomed`. In particular, your current code tries to select the axes from `container`:

   ```
   container.select(".x axis").call(xAxis);
   container.select(".y axis").call(yAxis);
   ```

   However, the axes are not children of `container`. Furthermore, you replaced the `.` required to select the axes by the class "axis" with a space. If instead you select the axes as children of the `svg` and setting the class selector properly, then your zoom behavior will work:

   ```
   svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
   svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
   ```
2. **Issue 2: The x-axis labeling is wrong.** This problem stems from the fact that you are adding the x-axis *before* loading your data. Thus, the domain of the x-axis hasn't been set using the dates of your data.

   The solution to this problem is to move all of the code that relies on the x-axis into your `d3.csv`. This way, when you add the axis or even when you zoom, the domain of the scale `x` for the x-axis has already been set properly. Here's the  updated Javascript that's working for me.

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {
        top: 10,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 570 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

```
// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([-width / 2, width / 2])
  .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([-height / 2, height / 2])
  .range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Get the data
d3.csv("data-hanta-gesamt.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%W-%Y").parse;
    d.meldewoche = parseDate(d.meldewoche);
    d.faelle = +d.faelle;
  });


  var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);

  var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.meldewoche);
    })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) {
      return y(d.faelle);
    })
    .interpolate("basis");

  var areaflip = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.meldewoche);
    })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) {
      return y(-d.faelle);
    })
    .interpolate("basis");

  // Define the line
  var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.meldewoche);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.faelle);
    })
    .interpolate("basis");

  var valuelineflip = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.meldewoche);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(-d.faelle);
    })
    .interpolate("basis");

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.meldewoche;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.faelle + 550;
  })]);

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

  var container = svg.append("g");

  var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // Add the valueline path.
  container.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data))
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,-265)");
  container.append("path")
    .attr("class", "lineflip")
    .attr("d", valuelineflip(data))
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,-265)");

  container.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,-265)");
  container.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "areaflip")
    .attr("d", areaflip)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,-265)");


  //ZOOM
  function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    //svg.selectAll('.line').attr('d', line)  
    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + ",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ",1)");

  }

  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
      .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But I think there's another problem with the zoom. It works, but the axis labels just get bigger (the font size gets bigger). It doesn't work like in the example that the axis labels change. There is the same issue with the line itself, the stroke width gets bigger, but I want to have a more detailed graph with the same stroke. Hope that explains the problem good enough.